# Baby Rudin Theorem 6.10

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Here is definition of Riemann Stieltjes integral:

> Let $\alpha$ be a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$ (since $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$ are finite, it follows that $\alpha$ is bounded on $[a, b]$). Corresponding to each partition $P$ of $[a, b]$, we write
> $$ \Delta \alpha_i = \alpha \left( x_i \right) -  \alpha \left( x_{i-1} \right). $$
> It is clear that $\Delta \alpha_i \geq 0$. For any real function $f$ which is bounded on $[a, b]$ we put
> $$ 
> \begin{align}
> U(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta \alpha_i, \\
> L(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta \alpha_i, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> where $M_i$, $m_i$ have the same meaning as in Definition 6.1, and we define
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \tag{5} \overline{\int_a^b} f d \alpha = \inf U(P, f, \alpha), \\
> \tag{6} \underline{\int_a^b} f d \alpha = \sup L(P, f, \alpha), \\\,
> \end{align}
> $$
> the $\inf$ and $\sup$ again being taken over all partitions. If the left members of (5) and (6) are equal, we denote their common value by
> $$ \tag{7} \int_a^b f d \alpha $$
> or sometimes by
> $$ \tag{8} \int_a^b f(x) d \alpha(x). $$
> This is the *Riemann-Stieltjes integral* (or simply the *Stieltjes integral*) of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$, over $[a, b]$.

> If (7) exists, i.e., if (5) and (6) are equal, we say that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$, in the Riemann sense, and write $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

And this is Rudin PMA's theorem 6.10:

> Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$, $f$ has only finitely many points of discontinuity on $[a, b]$, and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point at which $f$ is discontinuous. Then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

> **Proof**: Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Put $M = \sup \left\vert f(x) \right\vert$, let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous. Since $E$ is finite and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point of $E$, we can cover $E$ by finitely many disjoint intervals $\left[ u_j, v_j \right] \subset [a, b]$ such that the sum of the corresponding differences $\alpha\left(v_j\right) - \alpha \left( u_j \right)$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Furthermore, we can place these intervals in such a way that every point of $E \cap (a, b)$ lies in the interior of some $\left[ u_j, v_j \right]$.

> Remove the segments $\left( u_j, v_j \right)$ from $[a, b]$. The remaining set $K$ is compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, and there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\left\vert f(s) - f(t) \right\vert < \varepsilon$ if $s \in K$, $t \in K$, $\left\vert s-t \right\vert < \delta$.

> Now form a partition $P = \left\{ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\}$ of $[a, b]$, as follows: Each $u_j$ occurs in $P$. Each $v_j$ occurs in $P$. No point of any segment $\left( u_j, v_j \right)$ occurs in $P$. If $x_{i-1}$ is not one of the $u_j$, then $\Delta \alpha_i < \delta$.

> Note that $M_i - m_i \leq 2M$ for every $i$, and that $M_i - m_i \leq \varepsilon$ unless $x_{i-1}$ is one of the $u_j$. Hence, as in the proof of Theorem 6.8,
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] \varepsilon + 2M \varepsilon.$$
> Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, Theorem 6.6 shows that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

The part I do not understant is, why is the following true:

> Note that $M_i - m_i \leq 2M$ for every $i$, and that $M_i - m_i \leq \varepsilon$ unless $x_{i-1}$ is one of the $u_j$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first is due to the triangle inequality, the fact that $M$ is an upper bound of all values of the function and that $M_i$ and $m_i$ are particular values of the function. $|M_i-m_i|\leq |M_i|+|m_i|\leq M+ M=2M$. The second is due to the continuity of $f$ at the intervals where the inequality is asserted. In other words, the second paragraph of the proof, putting $s$ and $t$ the points where $f$ attains the values $M_i$ and $m_i$.

Comment: +1 for putting effort in adding all that context in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @plop mentioned in the comments, the first inequality can be proved using the triangle inequality. For the second one, uniform continuity of $f$ on $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and the fact that $\Delta x_i < \delta$ by construction ensures that $|f(s_i) - f(t_i)| = |M_i - m_i| \le \epsilon$ for some $s_i, t_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$.

Comment: But why does $x_{i-1}$ has to be one of the $u_j$?

Comment: @ Lanet $x_{i-1}$ should not be $u_j$ for second inequality to hold good. Read the word 'unless'. Your construction of $P$ is such that, you are not fixing the length $\delta$ for the interval of the type $[u_j, v_j]$. You are fixing the length of $\delta$ only when $x_{i-1}$ is not $u_j$.